# SELECT --> OPTION, using value vs ngValue

Tags: javascript, angular

I just recently figured out that there is an alternative for `value` property on OPTION part of the SELECT, namely `ngValue`. The docs really lack documentation about this (all I could find: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgSelectOption-directive.html). Anyway, the idea is that when you use an object for the `ngModel`, you can use `ngValue` and it works well. Otherwise, only e.g. ID is updated. If we're having just an array of strings, value is sufficient. Here are the examples:

```
{{myModel | json}}
<select [(ngModel)]="myModel">
  <option *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i">{{i.value}}</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

{{mySimpleModel}}
<select [(ngModel)]="mySimpleModel">
  <option *ngFor="let i of simpleItems" [value]="i">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

While this works as expected, there's a distinctive differences between the two: if using `ngValue`, the predefined value is not selected in the drop down, whereas for the primitive types, the value is selected on loading. E.g.:

```
items: any[] = [{id: 1, value: 'item1'}, {id: 2, value: 'item2'}, {id: 3, value: 'item3'}];
myModel: any = {id: this.items[1].id , value: this.items[1].value};

simpleItems: string[] = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
mySimpleModel: string = this.simpleItems[1];
```

See example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/JBrtmx7QkPZztBjaqYkS?p=preview
So, why does Angular set the default value for strings, but not for objects? And what is the most elegant workaround?

Comment: Great question. One point _please_ *never* write code like `items: any[] = [{id: 1, value: 'item1'}, {id: 2, value: 'item2'}, {id: 3, value: 'item3'}];` you are defeating the main benefit of TypeScript by doing that. Write `items = [{id: 1, value: 'item1'}, {id: 2, value: 'item2'}, {id: 3, value: 'item3'}];` instead. Type annotations, especially `any` are harmful when there is an initializer as they defeat static analysis, and shutdown typechecking.

Comment: `simpleItems: string[] = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];` is not harmful but is a waste of words. Leverage type inference.

Comment: I agree with you, this was solely for the purpose of writing an example as quickly as possible. I rarely use `any`. If necessary, I define an interface.

Comment: My point is that you don't need any annotation or an interface declaration because you have an initializer. That is to say it was not as quickly as possible since you wrote extra code : any[] that reduced the quality while taking more time to write. myModel: any = is even worse. You wrote more code to get a less well typed program. (Hint: the Angular docs exemplify awful TypeScript practices in many places)

Comment: I know this is out of scope, but it's interesting what you're saying, I always though that typing variables is A GOOD thing, e.g. `items: {id: number, value: string}[] = [{id: 1, value: 'item1'}, {id: 2, value: 'item2'}, {id: 3, value: 'item3'}];` but you said this is very wrong. Do you have a source or something where I could read more about this? I'm curious!

Comment: Basically typing variables is fine when it does not lose type information, but there is no need when there is an initializer. If the type annotation is `any` it is always strictly worse. As evidence, if you use an IDE (like VS Code), try to `.` off of `this.myModel`, somewhere in your constructor or in a method, where it is declared with and without an annotation. The results will speak form themselves.

Comment: For example if you write `myModel: any = {id: this.items[1].id , value: this.items[1].value};` you will get no completion when accessing `id` or `value` and the compiler will not validate that they exist because you have told the compiler "I know better!". It will also let you write `this.myModel.foobar()` and TypeScript will not complain because you overruled type inference. Your program will then explode at runtime. If you remove the type annotation then TypeScript will infer the type as "an object with an id property of type `number` and a value property of type `string`".

Comment: If you want a source watch Anders Hejlsberg's (the creator of TS) introduction to TypeScript when it was first announced. https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript this has always been part of the language.

Comment: I understand, thanks. so is the problem with any, or with typing in general? if i create an interface, is it better or not needed at all?

Comment: Depends on the situation. `any` is the main problem, but even with a better type, sometimes an inferred type is more accurate. For example a function returning `"a"` or `"b"` along different control flow paths would be inferred as returning the union type `"a" | "b"`. But we would probably annotate it with `string` which is worse. Interfaces are great whenever a type is reused or cannot be inferred. Also, annotating the parameters of freestanding functions and methods is good practice (not with `any` though) but do not annotate the parameters of a function value passed directly as a callback.

Comment: For example, this is a **good** use of types: 
`function f(id: number) { return id === 0 ? "a" : "b"; }` and
this is _less_ good (but OK) `function f(id: number): string { return id === 0 ? "a" : "b"; }`. Another example, this is **good**: `[1, "a"].map(x => x.toLocaleString())` and this is **very bad**: `[1, "a"].map((x: any) => x.toLocaleString())`.

Comment: RE: Interfaces: Just to clarify they are great, especially for APIs that deal with complex structures. EX: `interface Model { name: string; id: number }`. `class Component { model: Model; async ngOnInit() { this.model = await this.service.getModel(); } save() { this.service.saveModel(this.model) }`. `class Service { getModel(): Model {...} saveModel(model: Model) {...} }` Any situation like that is a great reason to use an interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a "workaround" for that. When you do this

```
myModel = {id: this.items[1].id , value: this.items[1].value};
```

you are creating a new object which has the same values as `this.items[1]` but it is **not** the same object, it's a new one.

```js
const items = [{id: 1, value: 'item1'}, {id: 2, value: 'item2'}, {id: 3, value: 'item3'}]

const myModel = {id: 2, value: 'item2'};

console.log(items[1] === myModel);
```

that is the reason why your select can't find that value in the `<option>` list.

In order to fix that, you have to use a proper reference

```
items = [
     {id: 1, value: 'item1'},
     {id: 2, value: 'item2'},
     {id: 3, value: 'item3'}
];
myModel = this.items[1]
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cZTzFNDwrP8BnGC2f8Hw?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up. Would you mind fixing the type safety of this answer by removing the annotations? Thanks! Upvoted!

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did wrong. These references to existing objects are really important when using Angular, as I've experienced a few times now.

Comment: @uglycode remember to upvote if the answer worked for you.

Comment: Worth to mention comparewith function.

Answer (score 4):

In order to obtain default selected option using [ngValue] you can use [compareWith].
Just change in the method compareObj the correct atribute for the Object your comparing.

```
<select [compareWith]="compareObj"  [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">
   <option *ngFor="let object of objects" [ngValue]="object">
      {{object.name}}
   </option>
</select>

compareObj(o1: Object, o2: Object) {
   return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```