# angular4 ngValue does not show selected value

Tags: angular, select

angular4

having trouble with select [ngValue] showing selected value from model

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.o">
<option *ngFor="let o of objs" [ngValue]="o"></option>
</select>
```

works fine but does not show selected object from model. but if i change `[ngValue]` to `[value]` it shows selected but then pass value as a string.

can some one help pls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT --> OPTION, using value vs ngValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442920/select-option-using-value-vs-ngvalue)

Comment: You can also use `[compareWith]` with Angular v 4. Just disregard the formcontrol in the answer from the link, and use ngmodel instead. But you get the idea from the answer on how to use it :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370348/6294072

Comment: [compareWith] worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

able to get it work using [compareWith] attribute.

Comment: Thanks. That also helped me

Answer (score -4):

Try This

```
<select name="model" [(ngModel)]="model.o">
    <option *ngFor="let o of objs" value="{{o}}">{{o}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you please suggest with [ngValue] instead of value as it doesn't take object. please refer below link `https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/65run4/select_option_using_value_vs_ngvalue/`. i want to disable inital value in dropdown with ngValue