# Can you change the style of datalist options?

Tags: css, html

I followed the solution on  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154877/use-html5-datalist-autocomplete-with-contains-approach-not-just-starts-wit) link to have my input field filter options in the datalist using contains instead of starts with.  The solution works but I have a problem with the display.  The options shows both the "value" and the "innerText" on the options list as shown below:

[image: datalist option list]

What I wanted to do is to make the first line smaller and the second line bigger but I am not sure if this is possible and what element should I style for this.

Here's the html code that I have:

```
            <div class="inputFieldBorder item item-input">
                <div class="row">
                <input type="text"
                       name="prodList"
                       id= "prodList"
                       maxlength = "50"
                       placeholder = "Things to Buy"
                       ng-model="listData.header.newProduct"
                       list="productlist">
                    <datalist id="productlist">
                        <select >&nbsp;
                            <option ng-repeat="productname in allproducts" value="{{productname.productName}}">{{productname.productName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </datalist>
                    <button ng-disabled="!listData.header.newProduct"
                      class="button button-icon ion-android-close input-button"
                      ng-click="clearSelection()"></button>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: additional info : This is part of an ionic app and I am doing the test in an android device.

Comment: Did you try using [ngValue] instead of value attribute? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442920/select-option-using-value-vs-ngvalue

Comment: Hope you found the answer, May I ask you a small favor ? How did you applied those styles to datalist I am now searching from 5 hours without any luck

Comment: @leoc Hope you see my comment above !